# Removing single quotes around downgraded angular 2 component's properties causes strange behavior

Tags: angularjs, angular, pug, angular-hybrid

I have a downgraded angular 2 component that works fine in an AngularJS component until I remove the single quotation marks around the component's second property.

EDIT: This filetype this component is used in is ng.jade .

This works:

```
user-score-component(
  [rating-score]="user.ratingScore"
  '[form-is-disabled]'="false"
  '(on-change)'="onRatingScoreChange($event)"
)
```

This doesn't:

```
user-score-component(
  [rating-score]="user.ratingScore"
  [form-is-disabled]="false"
  '(on-change)'="onRatingScoreChange($event)"
)
```

In the second example, false is applied to `rating-score` and `form-is-disabled` is undefined. I am fine leaving the single quotes around `form-is-disabled` but after some research on hybrid apps I haven't been able to figure out what the single quotes are doing here.

Why are they needed on the second property (`form-is-disabled`) but not the first (`rating-score`)?

Comment: Can you provide more context? I'm not sure I understand the syntax of the code you have pasted. It looks like a template literal of a function call, but the parameters are not seperated by commas and the there is no string delimiter, and typically, JS functions are not named with dashes. So confused.

Comment: Ahh! Jade. Now it makes sense. Thank you for adding that to your question. Also tagging your question with `pug` which is what Jade is now called

Comment: Thanks! It's my first question on SO and we work entirely with `pug` (this one file is still named ng.jade for some reason, I thought that might be a contributing factor) so I didn't think to add that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is mention of this on github in Pug's issue tracker: https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/2050

> This is a difficult case to solve. For example:
>
> ```
> input(foo='foo' [bar]='bar') //- since 'foo' [bar] is equivalent to
> 'foo'[bar] input(foo='foo'[bar]='bar') //- which is equivalent to
> input(foo=('foo'[bar]='bar')) //- which is equivalent to
> input(foo='bar')
>
> input([foo]='foo' (bar)='bar') input(foo='foo'(bar)='bar')
> input(foo=('foo'(bar)='bar')) //- 'foo'(bar)='bar → assigning to
> rvalue ?
> ```
>
> A work around you can use is quoting the attribute names:
>
> `input('[foo]'='foo' '[bar]'='bar') input('[foo]'='foo' '(bar)'='bar')`
>
> Since the bug is impossible to fix and a logical work around exists,
> I'm going to close this issue now.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly my issue. Oddly enough, when I changed the filetype from ng.jade to .pug it works just fine without the single quotes. It's possible we're doing something else to avoid this problem that I'm not aware of.